# internet connection availability in the browser

Tags: javascript, browser

We all know these online and offline events in the browser. It doesn't work very well (it does absolutely different thing).

Right now on our site it is implemented spamming our backend server every second with a request. I suggested to send head request to / of our domain and as it is Single Page Application, then it should be quite fast and no need to spam backend. But customer said that we can ping the gateway, THE FIRST POINT OF THE ISP.

I am not sure how to implement it in browser. First of all, not sure if it's easy to get in the browser ICP first point and then ping maybe disabled there, it is quite common practice.
Could you please suggest me anything ?

Comment: Why do you need to know whether you're online every second? Why not just try to make a routine request (save something, get some data, whatever), and if it fails, you know you're offline? No "spamming" needed.

Comment: basically, we show a black screen on our website if user doesn't have internet connection. Our project is related to video streaming. We use agora.io for video streaming. but there's no way to signal user in browser that he doesn't have internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just completed investigation of the proposal of my customer: ping gateway, first point of the ISP. Browser doesn't provide us such capabilities, in general idea might be good, though even if ping of this ip address works ok, it doesn't guarantee that internet is working, but anyway browser doesn't provide such capabilities, and ping (ICMP call) might be disabled on this ip address, so I'd go with my first idea: I'll handle it on nginx level (to avoid backend burden) and let's see how it works.